# Why DotNetBrowser not set permission granted in some site?

Tags: c#, geolocation, dotnetbrowser

Create an `Engine` instance:

```
engine = EngineFactory.Create(new EngineOptions.Builder
            {
                RenderingMode = RenderingMode.HardwareAccelerated,
                UserDataDirectory = folderBrowser,
                LicenseKey = lic,
                
                UserAgent = UA,
                GoogleApiKey = "input key",
                GoogleDefaultClientId = "put client id",
                GoogleDefaultClientSecret = "put secret"
            }
            .Build());
```

Grant permission for all permission requests:

```
engine.Permissions.RequestPermissionHandler =
    new Handler<RequestPermissionParameters, RequestPermissionResponse>(p =>
    {
            return RequestPermissionResponse.Grant();
    });
```

When I check geolocation in https://browserleaks.com/geo or https://geolocation.com/
I see that the geolocation permissions are granted and I see my actual coordinates:
[image]

But if I open other web site like https://google.com or https://yandex.ru - I see that permission - denied and geolocation does not work.
To check permission I create the following JS:

```
string perm = @"
var res;
var test = function(e){res=e};

navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'geolocation' }).then(result => {
      test(result.state)
})
res
";
```

When the Google or Yandex pages are downloaded, I execute this JS for check so:

```
string permiss = I.ActiveTab.browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript<string>(perm).Result;
string res = I.ActiveTab.browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript<string>("res").Result;
```

For https://browserleaks.com/geo or https://geolocation.com/ I have the "res" variable all time granted, but in Google or Yandex - I have "res" all time denied.

Why so? If I do not create `filtr` for URL when I create "engine.Permissions.RequestPermissionHandler".

I see that navigate not to page https://browserleaks.com/geo, DotNetBrowser does not go inside this code:

```
new Handler<RequestPermissionParameters, RequestPermissionResponse>(p =>
    {
            return RequestPermissionResponse.Grant();
    });
```

and in page all permissions are denied.
What do I need to do to go into `RequestPermissionHandler` every time for every web page?

Answer (score 1):

problem that geolocation not work in same page, becouse some page not send navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options); if navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'geolocation' }) - return denied and not send ask permission for this page, and in DotNetBrowser before sending request all permission is denied.

Now I make so string with js:

```
public static string askpermissiongeo = @"
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
  console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
  console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
}

function error(err) {
  console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
}


window.onload = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
";
```

and inject this code, when need turn on geolocation in some page:

```
b.InjectJsHandler = new Handler<InjectJsParameters>(args =>
    {
         IJsObject askperm = args.Frame.ExecuteJavaScript<IJsObject>(askpermissiongeo).Result;
    });
```

after this manipulation DotNetBrowser go to code:

```
engine.Permissions.RequestPermissionHandler =
    new Handler<RequestPermissionParameters, RequestPermissionResponse>(p =>
    {
        
            return RequestPermissionResponse.Grant();
        
    });
```

and all work